# Phalanger with cakephp

Tags: php, visual-studio-2008, cakephp, phalanger

Has anybody been able to use CakePHP in Visual Studio using Phalanger

Comment: could you restructure your question to be slightly more... specific? For example, are you having problems getting it to work? Are you just interested to hear people's experiences with it? Are you interested in performance issues? etc etc.

Comment: Agree with @nickf ... The possible answers to your questions are YES or NO !

Answer (score 2):

I've just tried. Using Phalanger 2.1 (march 2011) and CakePHP 2.0, there are just missing SplFileInfo and RuntimeException classes, that should be implemented soon hopefully.

I've used following command to compile the web:

> D:\inetpub\wwwroot\CakePHP>phpc /target:web /root:. /recurse:.

It can be debugged from VS2010 too, just create new WebSite and drop CakePHP folder content into the project.